# Why does error 'unexpected character after line continuation character' appear here?

Tags: python-3.x

Does someone know what is wrong with this section of my code as it seems to cause errors. I'm new to programming so I'm not completely sure what's wrong.

```py
menu = "Be Lenny's Friend?\n"
   1. Yes\n\
   2. No\n\
```

answer = int(input(menu))

```
if answer == 1:
    print(" ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°): Yayyyy! We are going to be friends!")

elif answer == 2:
    reason = input(" ( ͡° ʖ̯ ͡°): Why do you not want to be my friend :(")
```

Error message:

```
'unexpected character after line continuation character'
```

Comment: what ,\n: do after your string?

Comment: What you wand to do?

Comment: edited the answer to match with your edit

Answer (score 0):

Here you have set the variable as a tuple of a string and... well that’s where things get confusing. 
The backslash is a like continuation symbol as in you can then break the line and continue on and it would count as the same line. However what the interpreter sees is `n:` which makes no sense. That is what it is complaining about.

If you wanted to add a new line to the string itself, you could add the `\n` at the end of the string.

However, also note that if you printed the string using `print` in the vanilla form without any other arguments than the  Adrianne itself, it will append a new line automatically. So if you do add the `\n`, it may still not be what you want when you print it out. Parameter can of course be changed in the print function to take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to archive with `,\n\:` at the end of the line, but this line of code will remove the syntax error:

```
menu = "Be Lenny's Friend?"
```

If you want to archive a new line after the string you need to move "\n" into the string like this:

```
menu = "Be Lenny's Friend?\n"
```

**Edit:**

This should work for you:

```
menu = "Be Lenny's Friend?\n\t1. Yes\n\t2. No\n"
answer = int(input(menu))
if answer == 1: print(" ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°): Yayyyy! We are going to be friends!")

elif answer == 2: reason = input(" ( ͡° ʖ̯ ͡°): Why do you not want to be my friend :(\n")
```